# Using a Global Initial Date with Moment.js in a React Native Application

Tags: javascript, react-native, momentjs, moment-timezone

In our React Native application, we're using moment.js for various date and time manipulations. However, we need to set a global initial date and time, which should be used throughout the entire application for all moment.js operations.

Problem:
The main issue is how to set this global initial date and time so that any subsequent moment.js operations will use it as their base. Additionally, this initial date and time could be updated in one part of the application and should reflect immediately in all other parts.

I write the code like this but the time never increases. Does it remain constant?

```
export const setDefaultTime = (date: string, time: string) => {
  const serverDate = `${date} ${time}`;

  const serverMoment = moment.utc(serverDate);

  moment.now = function () {
    return serverMoment.valueOf();
  };
};
```

Then I use moment.now() on another page. It gives me the date and time, but the date and time never increase.

Comment: It is not clear why you would expect the date value to ever change. You only call `moment.utc()` once.

Comment: Sometimes users' phone dates may be wrong. That's why I'm getting the date value from the backend now. I want to give the date value I received to moment.js as default date time or initial date time. Then, wherever I use the moment, I want to make transactions with the date I give.

Comment: You cannot "fix" the clock on a client device. The `moment` time is based on the built-in JavaScript Date mechanism, which in turn uses the time on the device. You could detect the time difference and keep that around to adjust values you get from the client runtime, but you'll need to keep constructing new Date (or `moment`) objects.

Comment: What can I do in this situation?

Comment: Like I said, compare the timestamp from your server with what `Date.now()` produces, remember the difference, and then when you make new Date instances you can adjust forward or back as appropriate.

Comment: I will try this, but it is a very big project, I hope I can achieve it in a short time. Thank you for spending your time with me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can set the default date and time with this logic.

```
export const setDefaultTime = (date: string, time: string) => {
  const serverOffset = moment(`${date} ${time}`).diff(new Date());

  moment().add(serverOffset, 'milliseconds');

  moment.now = () => {
    return new Date().getTime() + serverOffset;
  };
};
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).